# force re.search to include # and $

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I am trying to get a substring between two markers using `re` in Python, for example:

```
import re
test_str = "#$ -N model_simulation 2022"

# these two lines work
# the output is: model_simulation
print(re.search("-N(.*)2022",test_str).group(1))
print(re.search(" -N(.*)2022",test_str).group(1))

# these two lines give the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
print(re.search("$ -N(.*)2022",test_str).group(1))
print(re.search("#$ -N(.*)2022",test_str).group(1))
```

I read the documentation of `re` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). It says that "#" is intentionally ignored so that the outputs look neater.

But in my case, I do need to include "#" and "$". I need them to identify the part of the string that I want, because the "-N" is not unique in my entire text string for real work.

Is there a way to force `re` to include those? Or is there a different way without using `re`?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you try raw string? ```match = r"#$ -N model_simulation 2022"```

Comment: try this
print(re.search("\$ -N(.*)2022",test_str).group(1))
print(re.search("\#\$ -N(.*)2022",test_str).group(1))

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea I can't do that, because in real work, the raw string changes all the time, and there are too many model simulation names. But, thanks!

Comment: @Jeremy Okay, I think escaping will be the best thing to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape both with `\`, for example,

```
print(re.search("\#\$ -N(.*)2022",test_str).group(1))
# output  model_simulation
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the special meaning by using the backslash prefix: $. This way, you can match the dollar symbol in a given string

```
# add backslash before # and $ 
# the output is: model_simulation
print(re.search("\$ -N(.*)2022",test_str).group(1))
print(re.search("\#\$ -N(.*)2022",test_str).group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions, `$` signals the end of the string. So `'foo'` would match `foo` anywhere in the string, but `'foo$'` only matches `foo` if it appears at the end. To solve this, you need to escape it by prefixing it with a backslash. That way it will match a literal `$` character

`#` is only the start of a comment in verbose mode using `re.VERBOSE` (which also ignores spaces), otherwise it just matches a literal `#`.

In general, it is also good practice to use raw string literals for regular expressions (`r'foo'`), which means Python will let backslashes alone so it doesn't conflict with regular expressions (that way you don't have to type `\\\\` to match a single backslash `\`).

Instead of `re.search`, it looks like you actually want `re.fullmatch`, which matches only if the whole string matches.

So I would write your code like this:

```
print(re.search(r"\$ -N(.*)2022", test_str).group(1)) # This one would not work with fullmatch, because it doesn't match at the start
print(re.fullmatch(r"#\$ -N(.*)2022", test_str).group(1))
```

---

In a comment you mentioned that the string you need to match changes all the time. In that case, `re.escape` may prove useful.

Example:

```
prefix = '#$ - N'
postfix = '2022'
print(re.fullmatch(re.escape(prefix) + '(.*)' + re.escape(postfix), tst_str).group(1))
```

Comment: your ````re.fullmatch```` indeed worked for my example in this post. But I don't why I still have that error in my real work. For the moment, I need to carry on with ````re.search()````, and if I can figure out why, I will accept yours as the answer later.